# Farm backup diiference by using powershell and sharepoint admin console

Tags: sharepoint-server, backup, farm

Is there any difference to take farm back up by using power shell and SharePoint admin console.

When I use GET-SPDATABASE Command, it was showing around 76 GB.How ever when I use SharePoint admin console it is only 25 GB and farm back up completed successfully.Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Get-SPDatabase (run with disk size) will give you the current size of content database (include both data and logs file), this is not backup size.

But when you run the backup, it shrink the files & compressed it.

So this is not good comparison.